# Displaying rows, extracted from a database, one by one in a DataGrid

Tags: php, apache-flex

I have a table (session) in a database which has almost 72,000 rows. I extract those rows with the help php+mysql but when the result is returned to the HTTPService, i need to wait for some 32 seconds before the all the rows start appearing in the DataGrid at once.

**Question**
Is there any way by which DataGrid may start displaying data one by one while the application may extract next rows in parallel. Or that the DataGrid may show data in chunks of hundreds. Like when application starts, it may show first 400 enteries in DataGrid, then the next 400 hundred are extracted until all the 72,000 rows are extracted?

Or can i involve threading such that one thread may be responsible for displaying data in datagrid while the other, executing in parallel may be responsible for extracting next data from database?

Thanks a lot guys as always.

```
<mx:HTTPService id="populateTable" url="request.php" method="POST"  resultFormat="e4x">
     <mx:request xmlns="">
        <getResult>table</getResult>
     </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

code from PHP file

```
function populateTable()
{
   $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session" );

   $Return = "<Sessions>";
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $Result ) )
   {
     $Return .= "<session><no>".$no."</no>" . 
                "<srcIP>".$row->srcIP."</srcIP>" .
               "<dstIP>".$row->dstIP."</dstIP>" .
                "<sPort>".$row->sPort."</sPort>" .
                "<dPort>".$row->dPort."</dPort>" .
                "<sessionID>".$row->sessionID."</sessionID>" .
                "<numberOfConnections>".$row->numberOfConnections."</numberOfConnections>" .
                "</session>";
   }
     $Return .= "</Sessions>";
  // mysql_free_result( $Result );

   echo $Return;
}
```

Comment: If you're able to use JS, you could use AJAX to start a buffer of the data as it's returned in the PHP file, reloading the DataGrid with the new contents at predetermined increments.

Comment: Why is this question community wiki? FYI, votes in community wiki questions doesn't carry any reputation points and hence users are less likely to answer such questions except for general discussion/subjective threads. Its not a good idea to mark your questions cw if you intend to attract people. Personally speaking, I might have considered spending some time to add some code to my answer if this wasn't marked CW. Reputations are the incentives we get here, don't deny it :)

Comment: Oh no Amarghosh. Franky i don't even know what community wiki is :P

I just noticed the check box today so clicked to see what does it do. Is there any way i can remove it from community wiki?

Comment: Community wiki is to be used only for subjective/argumentative/slightly-off-topic questions and questions with no definite answer. I think cw is irreversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider redesigning the app. No sane user is gonna need to see the whole 72K of data at the same time.

- Change the php script so that it accepts a startIndex parameter and selects 100 rows from that index instead of selecting `*`.
- Add Next page/Previous page buttons in the flex app that causes `HTTPService` to be resend with changed startIndex value. Bind the `lastResult` of the `HTTPService` to the DataGrids `dataProvider`.

Update:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="service" resultFormat="e4x"/>
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{service.lastResult}">
  <!-- columns -->
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:Button label="Next" click="next()"/>
<mx:Button label="Prev" click="prev()"/>
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private var currentIndex:Number = 0;
    private var itemsPerPage:Number = 100;
    private var total:Number = 72000;
    private function next():void
    {
      if(currentIndex + 1 >= total/itemsPerPage)
        return;
      currentIndex++;
      service.url = "request.php?page=" + currentIndex;
      service.send();
    }
    private function prev():void
    {
      if(currentIndex == 0)
        return;
      currentIndex--;
      service.url = "request.php?page" + currentIndex;
      service.send();
    }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Here I've appended the index to the url itself. You may also use the [request](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#request) property of `HTTPService` to send the data.

In php, change the query `"SELECT * FROM session"` so that it selects only 100 queries based on the value of `$_GET["page"]`.

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh but please don't punish me for making this post a community wiki, by not spending time to add some code to your answer :)

Comment: Thanks a million Amarghosh. Now, updating my code according to your suggestion, even though i won't always know, in advance, the number of rows in the table being accessed from a database.

Comment: 14 questions and 0 votes : Do you know how stack overflow work? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow/7238#7238

Comment: I guess so...Went through the link you mentioned. I think i will get votes only if i answer some question. And if i don't, my reputation will not go down :)

But i will like it to increase for sure. And whenever i come across some question whose ans i know i will definitely reply to it.

Comment: You are right: You answer questions, people find them helpful and vote you up and you gain reps. Now, ever wondered how those people (who answer your questions) gain reps...?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to remind you is that despite having asked 15 questions with many accepted answers you have never cast a single vote so far. Consider going back to your questions and clicking the up arrow button near the helpful answers - that's how they gain reps.

Comment: May be you were not aware of this thing at all - but people may find this as a hostile attitude and ignore your questions.

Comment: That is all good for getting the rows starting at an index, but if the datagrid is sorted you are now out of luck so you will have to make sure to add a sort property to your call.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, the query should account for required sorting